# Disable certain dates from html5 datepicker

Tags: html, date, datepicker

Is it possible to disable dates when I use 

I want to disable current date for one scenario and future dates for other scenario.
How should I disable the dates?

Answer (score 97):

[You can add a `min` or `max` attribute to the `input type=date`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/date). The date must be in ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd). This is supported in many mobile browsers and current versions of Chrome, although users can manually enter an invalid date without using the datepicker.

```html
<input name="somedate" type="date" min="2013-12-25">
```

The `min` and `max` attributes *must* be a full date; there's no way to specify "today" or "`+0`". To do that, you'll need to use JavaScript or a server-side language:

```js
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementsByName("somedate")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/kz7d2/

Ruling out only today, while allowing past or future dates, is not an option with here. However, if you meant you want tomorrow to be the `min` date (blanking out today and all past dates), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3674539/901048) to increment `today` by one day.

As in all other cases involving HTML forms, you should always validate the field server-side regardless of how you constrain it client-side.

Comment: @Pasta Yes, it does. Did you have a specific problem implementing it?

Comment: If user insert a date by input instead of by calendar, this doesn't work :(

Comment: @smartmouse That is true; some kind of JavaScript `onblur` event (in addition to server-side validation) would be needed to deal with that.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. I'm using the Laravel and Livewire so according to my business logic I'm loading min date from livewire module like this. Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');

Comment: Can you do the same thing with TimePickers?

Answer (score 14):

In pure HTML, the only restrictions you can put on dates are its lower and upper bounds through the `min` and `max` attributes. In the example below, only the dates of the week I'm posting this question are allowed, other appear greyed out and clicking on them doesn't update the input value:

```html
<input type="date" min="2019-06-02" max="2019-06-08"/>
```

You can also disable any invalid date by using a few lines of JavaScript, but this doesn't ship with all the native `<input type="date">` features like greyed-out dates. What you can do is set the date value to `''` in case of an invalid date, an error message could also be displayed. Here is an example of an input that doesn't accept weekend dates:

```js
// Everything except weekend days
const validate = dateString => {
  const day = (new Date(dateString)).getDay();
  if (day==0 || day==6) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

// Sets the value to '' in case of an invalid date
document.querySelector('input').onchange = evt => {
  if (!validate(evt.target.value)) {
    evt.target.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date"/>
```

Comment: if one wants to change it such so only today and tomorrow were not selectable? Thanks

Comment: I think this has more flexibility for styling and response, especially with Laravel so +1 to that.

Answer (score 4):

HTML datepicker (`<input type=date>`) supports `min`/`max` attribute. It is [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) nowadays.

References:

[W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html)

Comment: Your "not widely supported" link says it has 96.29% global support.

Answer (score 4):

You could use this to disable future dates :
Inside you `document.ready` function, place

```
//Display Only Date till today //

var dtToday = new Date();
var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;     // getMonth() is zero-based
var day = dtToday.getDate();
var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
if(month < 10)
   month = '0' + month.toString();
if(day < 10)
   day = '0' + day.toString();

var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
$('#dateID').attr('max', maxDate);
```

and in form

```
<input id="dateID" type="date"/>
```

Here is the working [jFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jdb12f5t/)

Answer (score 4):

For react and similar libraries, you may use this to disable all dates before today.

`<input  type='date' min={new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]} >`

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you need, you can also use the `step` attribute to only enable specific dates - e.g. every Monday, or every other day. You can use it in combination with `min` and `max`

e.g. every Monday

```html
<input type="date" step="7" value="2022-04-04">
```

Every Thursday

```html
<input type="date" step="7" value="2022-04-07">
```

Every other day

```html
<input type="date" step="2">
```