# HTML5 datepicker prevent past dates

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a website for booking movie tickets. What should I set the `min` attribute to, to prevent past dates in the HTML5 datepicker? (I do not want to use PHP solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182544/disable-certain-dates-from-html5-datepicker).)

Is there a pure HTML5/Javascript solution for this?

Comment: If you actually mean the HTML5 `<input type="date">`, not some jQuery plugin, just set `min="2014-01-01"` would be sufficient.

Comment: That would be static. How do I make it dynamic?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"? You can always use DOM to manipulate the attribute, it's all standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the document loads have the date input disabled.  Run an `onload` function that inserts today's date into the min field in the required format.

```
function onLoad() {
  var input = document.getElementById("dateField");
  var today = new Date();
  // Set month and day to string to add leading 0
  var day = new String(today.getDate());
  var mon = new String(today.getMonth()+1); //January is 0!
  var yr = today.getFullYear();

    if(day.length < 2) { day = "0" + day; }
    if(mon.length < 2) { mon = "0" + mon; }

    var date = new String( yr + '-' + mon + '-' + day );

  input.disabled = false; 
  input.setAttribute('min', date);
}

document.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false);

<body>
  <input id="dateField" type="date" disabled  />
</body>
```

Here it is in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tj9Xh/2/

Comment: I updated the day to be a string as well.  It's the 27th so I didn't think about single digit dates until after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<input id="dateField" type="date"/>


 var dt= new Date();
   var yyyy = dt.getFullYear().toString();
   var mm = (dt.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
   var dd  = dt.getDate().toString();
   var min = yyyy +'-'+ (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) +'-'+ (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]); // padding
alert(min);
$('#dateField').prop('min',min);
```