# How to disable past days and weekends with BootStrap datepicker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a BS input with `type="date"` and all I am trying to do is to disable past days and weekends in my calendar. I tried numerous snippets of code found on the internet and invented by me, but nothing worked, probably because I lack understanding how to make them work.

So please help. Any tips will be appreciated.

Here is my html :

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date" ">Date:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datepicker">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396605/html5-datepicker-prevent-past-dates

Answer (score 2):

Try following, it will indicate minimum date & weekend disable in this control.

```
 $(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        minDate : 'now'
     });
 });
```

Comment: Does this work with you? Because i tried it and it doesn't work. I am just wondering what i did wrong..

Answer (score 0):

you can set a start data like this:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);

$('#date').datepicker({ 
    startDate: date
});
```

and disble any day you want with this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]
});
```