# javascript function (input date bigger than today date)

Tags: javascript, html, function, date

I'm starter in javascript :

I need a function that detect if user input a date .. and alert him if the date is smaller than today date ...

HTML :

```
 <input type="date" name="StartDate" id="userdate"  required />
```

JavaScript I tried (didn't work of course ):

```
function TDate() {
var UserDate = document.getElementById("userdate").value;
var ToDate = Date.now();
if (UserDate != ToDate) {
    alert("The Date must be Bigger or Equal to today date")
    return false;
}
return true;}
```

Comment: What format is userdate? What today do you want? The users today or your possibly different today?

Comment: the system or server today .... 
example :

user input 17/11/2015 
but today in server or in system date is : 18/11/2015

I need the function to alert the user that he inserted a restricted date and focus on date  to change it

Comment: kindly mark the best answer :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have created a fiddle

https://jsbin.com/jidogo/edit?html,js,output

```
<input type="date" name="StartDate" id="userdate" onchange="TDate()" required />
```

JS

```
function TDate() {
    var UserDate = document.getElementById("userdate").value;
    var ToDate = new Date();

    if (new Date(UserDate).getTime() <= ToDate.getTime()) {
          alert("The Date must be Bigger or Equal to today date");
          return false;
     }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: it is good ,,, but when I insert the date manually it start alerting from the first value in the year section .... I think it need a button and an (onclick) event ... right ?

Comment: Actually I did this earlier but then changed as I was expecting that you need validation on change, but you are right, add a button like `<button onclick="TDate()">Validate</button>` and remove `onchange` attribute from input

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you can get the selected Date object by `var selectedDate = document.getElementById("userdate").value`. Then you can compare two date like compare 2 integer number:

```
function TDate() {
    var selectedDate = document.getElementById("userdate").value;
    if (selectedDate < Date.now()) {
        alert("The Date must be Bigger or Equal to today date")
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the accepted answer checks by time.
as the input type is "date", the milliseconds are 000 
**to compare for day**

```
var variable1 = new Date();
var variable2 = variable1.toISOString().split('T')[0];
if (new Date($("#userdate").val()).getTime() < new Date(variable2).getTime()) {
    //input date less than todays date
}else{
    //input date bigger than todays date
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be cleaner than other answers thanks to [Juank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26749559/3078890):

```
var now = new Date(),
    minDate = now.toISOString().substring(0,10);

$('#my-date-input').prop('min', minDate);
```