# How do I restrict past dates in HTML5 input type Date?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to restrict past dates in `input type="date"`. I am able to restrict future dates, but how can I restrict past dates?

```js
$(function(){
    var dtToday = new Date();

    var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = dtToday.getDate();
    var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
    if(month < 10)
        month = '0' + month.toString();
    if(day < 10)
        day = '0' + day.toString();

    var minDate= year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

    $('#txtDate').attr('min', minDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="txtDate" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict future dates in HTML 5 data input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671407/restrict-future-dates-in-html-5-data-input)

Comment: @Esko that is future dates right?

Comment: Both, min and max, if min date is today, then you can't select yesterday.

Comment: I see no problem there. The snippet in your question just works fine!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try this

```
 var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    alert(maxDate);
    $('#txtDate').attr('min', maxDate);
```

```js
$(function(){
    var dtToday = new Date();
    
    var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = dtToday.getDate();
    var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
    if(month < 10)
        month = '0' + month.toString();
    if(day < 10)
        day = '0' + day.toString();
    
    var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

    // or instead:
    // var maxDate = dtToday.toISOString().substr(0, 10);

    alert(maxDate);
    $('#txtDate').attr('min', maxDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="txtDate" />
```

Answer (score 23):

Here is a PHP solution that gets today's date and sets it as the minimum.

```
<input type="date" id="txtDate" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>">
```

This will put it in the correct double-digit format for the day and month. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: or using laravel templating: <input type="date" id="txtDate" min="{{date("Y-m-d")}}">

Answer (score 21):

The below code may help you. It is normal HTML5 code:

Enter a date before 1980-01-01:

```
<input type="date" name="bday" max="1979-12-31">
```

Enter a date after 2000-01-01:

```
<input type="date" name="bday" min="2000-01-02">
```

See [this working example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min).

Answer (score 21):

Programmatically you can do something like this to disable past dates from being selectable:

```
<input type='date' min={new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]} />
```

Comment: Thanks Muhamed for the tip :-)

Comment: @MuhamedKrashi what about if i wanna only able to choose last 45 days??

Comment: Could you please explain what 'T' stands for ? because I console.log that and didn't see T

Comment: @greenridinghood thats only for disabling past dates. For implementing any logic then you need to use javascript or write some code for more complex scenarious.

Comment: @Erika usually a datetime is in a format like: 2023-09-06T23:30:00, so we split it by the T in the middle which means split the date and time and then get the date part.

Answer (score 4):

In HTML:

```
<input type="date" id="ExpiryDate" class="form-control" min="9/10/2018"/>
```

Using Jquery new version:

```
function SetMinDate() {
    var now = new Date();

    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

    var today = now.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);

    $('#ExpiryDate').val(today);
    $('#ExpiryDate').attr('min', today); }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="date" id="date"> 
var date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);

//To restrict past date

$('#date').attr('min', date);

//To restrict future date

$('#date').attr('max', date);
```

Comment: It would be ideal to provide additional info to the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(function() {
          $(document).ready(function () {
            var todaysDate = new Date();
            var year = todaysDate.getFullYear();
            var month = ("0" + (todaysDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
            var day = ("0" + todaysDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
            var maxDate = (year +"-"+ month +"-"+ day);
            $('.class_of_input_field').attr('min',maxDate);
          });
        });``
```

Comment: Hi! It would make your answer more useful if you provide some extra explanation/context (ex what advantage it offers from other answers, what was wrong with the original snippet etc).

Answer (score 1):

> To select To date greater than from date we can use this code

```js
 $(document).on("change", "#from", function () {
        debugger
        var date = $(this).val();
       
        $('#to').attr('min', date);
    
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
    var dtToday = new Date();
    
    var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = dtToday.getDate();
    var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
    if(month < 10)
        month = '0' + month.toString();
    if(day < 10)
        day = '0' + day.toString();
    
    var minDate= year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    
    $('#date').attr('min', minDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="date" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using laravel then just do it like this

```
<input type="date" name="start_date" required min="{{date('Y-m-d')}}" />
```

and for regular HTML just specify the date

```
<input type="date" name="start_date" required min="2022-07-18" />
```

Answer (score 0):

in laravel 5.8,

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="from_date" id="from_date"required min="{{date('Y-m-d')}}"  value="{{ old('from_date') }}">
```

here, i used `min="{{date('Y-m-d')}}"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've found this working (HTML) method. (i.e this works with only textbox with date mode, not with calendars or date-time pickers.)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var today = new Date();
        var month = ('0' + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        var day = ('0' + today.getDate()).slice(-2);
        var year = today.getFullYear();
        var date = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
        $('[id*=txtExpDate]').attr('min', date);
    });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtExpDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

i use something like this
i have my input tag

```
<input name="Date" type="date" onkeyup="checkdate(this)" onchange="checkdate(this)" class="form-control">
```

and the function is

```
function checkdate(e){

if(new Date(e.value)-new Date()<0){e.value='';

e.style.border="1px solid red"



return false}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict date input to be >= the current date like so:

```js
var today = new Date();
var formattedDate = today.toISOString().split('T')[0];

// jQuery    
$('#txtDate').attr({'min' : formattedDate});

// Vanilla JS
document.getElementById('txtDate').min = formattedDate
```