# I want to disable dates before today and using a input html "datepicker" in React, how can I make this possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

I want to disable dates before today and using a input html "datepicker" in React, how can I make this possible?

```
          <div className="form-group">
                <label className="label" htmlFor="date" >Date</label>
                <Input
                    className="form-control" id="date"
                    type="date"
                    name="date"
                    value={user.date}
                    onChange={(e) => handleUser(e)}
                    required
                />
            </div>
```

[image: This is what I want to achieve]

Comment: Surely looks like you use a package, in that case mention the package name and go through the docs, this functionality is very common for datepickers

Comment: It' not a package, it the default date form html that I use. I found this: http://jsfiddle.net/tj9Xh/2/ , but I don't know how to implement this to react.

Comment: You can add a `min` attribute. Check out answers in the duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restrict past dates in html5 input type Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274559/how-do-i-restrict-past-dates-in-html5-input-type-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a min attribute to the Component

```
 <Form.Control
   type="date"
   min={formatDate(new Date())}
 />
```

and in the formatDate function you can disable the previous date

```
const formatDate = (date) => {
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
    const day = String(start);
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
 };
```