# How can I only allow up to one year from today's date to be selected from datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I have my calendar working and set up so that paste dates are disabled according from today's date. How can I also disable dates after 365 days from the current date?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ts8acmow/1/

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
document.getElementById("start").setAttribute("min", today);
```

Comment: The HTML element should let you set a min and max date as attributes, does that not work in this case?

Comment: but I want it to update dynamically depending on the current date. ie: 365 days from todays date =4/25/2020

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add year to todays date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070428/add-year-to-todays-date)

Comment: You should be able to use JS to set the value of that attribute.

Comment: can you update the fiddle?

Comment: @imvain2 I think that it's a relevant difference from your linked question that OP doesn't just want to add a year in JS, but to set that calculated date as the max date for an input field.

Comment: @bluemoon6790 I linked that because when you mentioned setting the min max date, the OP was more focused on the dynamic part and not the `max` field part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict future dates in HTML 5 date input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671407/restrict-future-dates-in-html-5-date-input)

Comment: yes I do not know how

Comment: @imvain2 Fair enough.  I was thinking about the HTML element when OP mentioned they want to "disable" invalid dates.

Comment: I have already achieved the disable of past dates how I want it but I just now want to disable future dates one year from current date

Answer (score 3):

It is really the same principle, but for the `max` attribute.

Here is how you could do it:

```js
function fmt(dt) {
    return dt.toLocaleDateString("se"); // shortcut: Sweden locale has YYYY-MM-DD format
}

var today365 = new Date();
today365.setDate(today365.getDate()+365);

var start = document.getElementById("start");
start.setAttribute("min", fmt(new Date()));
start.setAttribute("max", fmt(today365));
```

```html
<input type="date" id="start">
```

Comment: that doesn't work, that still allows me to go further than a year from today. also past dates have to stay disabled

Comment: The way `min` and `max` attributes work is not to block, but to indicate the invalid entry with a visual indication, like a red border. I thought that was what you wanted, as you stated in your question that you got it working for past dates. This is just the same principle, so I don't understand why you see a problem here.

Comment: because I don't know how to disable the future dates so only 1 year from today is allowed to be chosen from

Comment: If you add: `start.addEventListener("change",function(){
   if(this.max < this.value){
      this.value = this.max;
   }
});` it will set the field's value to the max value if a date is greater than the max date is selected.

Comment: In your fiddle also past dates can be *selected* (using the arrows in Chrome, or the popup in FF) , so then I don't understand why you start your question by stating that it disables past dates if yet it is not what you want. On the other hand, in the popup calendar (in FF) the dates beyond one year are greyed out as intended, just like those before today's date.

Answer (score 0):

Using Moment.js to get the date 365 days from now in the 'YYYY-MM-DD' format
you can pass max attribute

```js
start.setAttribute("max", getMaxDate());

function getMaxDate() {
  return moment().add(365, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}
```