# How can I use input type date to dynamically only allow for one year from current date?

Tags: javascript, html, date, input

Here is my code so far. I am not sure how to accomplish a max date other than setting that in the input tag itself. I want it to be dynamic so whatever the current date is, the calendar only allows a selection of up to one year.

```
<input type="date" id="txtDate" />
```

```
$(function(){
    var dtToday = new Date();

    var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = dtToday.getDate();
    var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
    if(month < 10)
        month = '0' + month.toString();
    if(day < 10)
        day = '0' + day.toString();

    var maxDate = dtToday + 365;
    alert(maxDate);
    $('#txtDate').attr('max', maxDate);
});
```

example: today is 10/1/2019 it should be allowed to only select dated from 10/1/2019-10/1/2020 tomorrow a user should be allowed to only select from 10/2/2019-10/2/2020
[link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/10fy3x7k/1/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict future dates in HTML 5 date input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671407/restrict-future-dates-in-html-5-date-input)

Comment: @ShayaUlman this doesn't appear to be a duplicate. The question is about setting a dynamic end date

Comment: @ControlAltDel yes exactly. I only want to allow a date selection from the current date + 1 year from the current day

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/qf32ync0/ (it *is* a dupe of that question btw, but the accepted answer doesn't use good practice to create the `max` string)

Comment: @ControlAltDel, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23671540/10679649) over there seems to answer this question, how is about that?

Comment: yeah that is perfect, but how do I disallow for all dates starting before current date?

Comment: @Abigail just set minDate with the day, month, year of new Date()

Comment: @ShayaUlman Yes, this covers the max date part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the min and max values for a date input based on today's date can be done when the page loads:

```js
// Formt date as YYYY-MM-DD
function formatISOLocal(d) {
  let z = n => ('0' + n).slice(-2);
  return d.getFullYear()+'-'+z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' + z(d.getDate());
}

window.onload = function() {
  let inp = document.querySelector('#i0');
  let d = new Date();
  inp.min = formatISOLocal(d);
  inp.defaultValue = inp.min;
  d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);
  inp.max = formatISOLocal(d);
  // Debug
  console.log(inp.outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="i0">
```

If the user agent doesn't support input type date, this will still set the min/max/default values, but you'll have to handle out of range values yourself.

Comment: hey is there a way to use this script for more than one date type input fields? http://jsfiddle.net/eLp8n9d6/5/

Comment: Yes. If you have another question, post it as a question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a year to the current date

```
var dtToday = new Date();
dtToday.setYear(dtToday.getYear() + 1);
```

Comment: I also dont want the ability to have a date get selected if it is before the current date or over one year past the current date

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  var dtToday = new Date();
  dtToday.setFullYear(dtToday.getFullYear() + 1)
  let formatted_date = dtToday.getFullYear() + "-" + (dtToday.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dtToday.getDate()
  alert(formatted_date);
  $('#txtDate').attr('max', formatted_date);
});
```

Comment: but how can I disallow the selection of a date past 1 year from current date?

Comment: Just subtract 1 instead of adding and set attribute min: like this <input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
       value="2018-07-22"
       min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31">

Comment: @Abigail If you wanna disallow past dates then set min = current date

Comment: But wouldnt that be a static min date? I want it to update dynamically as the days go on

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: @James Dullat - make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks @help-info.de for letting me know

Answer (score -1):

You can't add to a date object like that; you need to first get it as a timestamp. You can do that by using `Date.now()` or, if you need the Date object, `dtToday.getTime()`.

That gives you a timestamp in milliseconds, so you also need to convert 365 days into milliseconds; meaning you want to add `365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` to it, not just 365.

Comment: thank you that makes sense but can you update fiddle please?

Comment: You can add either days or milliseconds to a date. The simplest way is to add 1 year, which takes account of leap years too (provided you accept the ECMAScript rules for adding a year to 29 February): `date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1)`.