# Is there a datetime-local attribute in HTML that only lets the user select dates from 'today' to future dates similar to 'min' and 'max'?

Tags: html, forms, date, datetime, input

Some HTML `<input>` tags will allow for `min` and `max` values like the numeric input type.  I was wondering if there's also such an attribute for the `datetime-local` input type where it can be set to a `min` value of the current `'today'` date?

Is it possible in HTML to set a selection limit for `datetime-local` input to only let the user be able to **only select dates ranging from** `'today'` **to future dates** while **preventing** the user from selecting past dates.

```html
<form>
  <input type="datetime-local">  
</form>
```

Comment: Per the HTML spec, you can set `min` and `max` on `<input type="type=datetime-local">`, though I’m not sure which browsers support it. And I think it only affects what the date picker shows and doesn’t prevent users from directly entering any date they want. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182544/disable-certain-dates-from-html5-datepicker/20782479#20782479 for a hint at how you can more easily set the date constraints on the server side (the example is in PHP but you can use the same mechanism in other server-side languages).

Comment: I have the same issue, there are methods to get only the future dates but no way to get future values for `<input type="datetime-local">`