# Is there a way to disable future time using input type= time

Tags: javascript, android, html, forms

Is there a way to disable future time input using

```
<input type='time'>
```

I want the time to be restricted from 9 am to 3 pm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable certain dates from html5 datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182544/disable-certain-dates-from-html5-datepicker)

Comment: Here I wanted to disable the time using timepicker.

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Use `min`, `max` and `pattern` attributes:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Select a time:
  <input type="time" name="usr_time" min="09:00" max="15:00" pattern="(09|1[0-5]):[0-5]\d">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes. but when I specify 9 am to 6 pm . I am able to select 7 pm . Is there a way using javascript or jquery .. I can achieve the same.

Comment: this will only work if input type time is supported by your browsers. you can check here http://www.html5accessibility.com/

Comment: Thank you for the response, it supports my browser. It works fine if min and max is either fore noon or afternoon. But if i try to add min as forenoon and max as afternoon, it does not work as expected.