# Disable back date entries in input type 'date'

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using input type date in my project instead of datepicker. I want to restrict back dates from current date in input type date.  I know about how to restrict back dates in datepicker but i dont want to use it.

Hence Please suggest is it possible to restrict back dates in input type date (html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable certain dates from html5 datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182544/disable-certain-dates-from-html5-datepicker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the min value of input in Javascript, like this:

```
    document.getElementById("myDate").min = "2017-03-16";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var inputMyDate = document.querySelector('input#finaldate');

inputMyDate.addEventListener('input', function() {  
    var current = this.value;               
    var today = new Date();     
    var dd = today.getDate();       
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd;
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm;
    } 
    var today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;                     
    if (current < today){
        document.getElementById('finaldate').value = today;
    }       
});
```