# How to disable previous dates in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, date

I am using simple angularjs input type = date for displaying date picker.

How to disable the previous dates means dates before the current dates.

html is like

```html
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="sevadate" ng-model="sevadate" min-date="" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-required="true" /> //What do i write in min-date..
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable certain dates from html5 datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182544/disable-certain-dates-from-html5-datepicker)

Comment: its html5. i want to use angular date picker. how to specify min date value?

Answer (score 0):

change  `min-date=""` to `min="2017-12-30"`

or you can do something like this  `min="{{minDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}} "`  and on the controller

```
  $scope.minDate = new Date();
```

```html
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="sevadate" ng-model="sevadate" min="2017-04-12" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-required="true" /> //What do i write in min-date..
```