# Restrict a date in a "html date field" without to Datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, date

I'm working with laravel and I want to know if there are a way to restrict a date in a html date field, when I use a field type Date, I can display a Calendar in the view, and I want to restric a date in that calendar.

For example: 
-I want to restric the dates that are less than today. 
-I want to compare that the second field that is not less than the first.

In the Calendar desable those dates. Are there a way to do that?

I don´t want to use  datepicker, just html date field and some script to make that possible, and use it in a global way, in all my date fields.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19253547/17300) from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17182544/17300)
Also note - some browsers don't implement a date-picker (Firefox 52 supports `type="date"` but doesn't have a datepicker), and the min/max attributes don't prevent you from typing in a date that's out of range — they just prevent you from _picking_ one.