# how to disable the list of dates array in html5 datepicker

Tags: html, datepicker

how to disable the list of dates array in html5 datepicker, for example, I have date array `const datelist = ["12-04-2019", "15-04-2019", "20-04-2019", "25-04-2019"]` i need to disable this specific dates in my datepicker. how can I archive this in the HTML5 date picker? Without using any plugins

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable certain dates from html5 datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182544/disable-certain-dates-from-html5-datepicker)

Comment: @SebastianBrosch pls try to understand my question is different