# How to make datetime-local input with disabled specified dates

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I'm creating website with form that user can choose date for doctor's appointment and some of dates should be disabled (fo example doctor has another appoitment). Dates will be in database with datetime-local format and i want to select them and disable.

I found only min and max attribute but i can't multiple it, step attribute is not resolving my problem.

I can select these dates but i need to remove them from calendar or make them unchoosable.

Comment: Could you show a sample of your code, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable certain dates from html5 datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182544/disable-certain-dates-from-html5-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling specific dates while using the simple `<input type='date' />` is not possible. You would either need to check the date against a list of dates *after* it is selected, or use a datepicker library.