# how can i prevent choosing sevral dates in html date input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, html-input

Am developing a booking website where people choose checkin and checkout, so let's assume that the chosen room is busy  from 20 till 30.

my input would be like

```
<input id="check_in" name="check_in" type="date"   value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Check-in"   required min="30" >
```

am trying to prevent user from choosing bettween 20 and 30

but all i can do in this html tag is preventing from choosing before 30 .

and also am assuming that the room can be busy from 1 to ,and from 20 to 30,
how to let user choose bettween 10 and 20 ?

Comment: you'll probably need some JS to check if the selected date is between 20 and 30 (and if so, reject it). This is not possible with pure HTML I think.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable certain dates from html5 datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182544/disable-certain-dates-from-html5-datepicker)

Comment: @yesterday The questioner added the javascript tag. I think is conscious abaut using Javascript.

Comment: @Natrium thank you for helping, but no it's not my question! i want to prevent a sevral dates not only one

Comment: @Natrium bro this question was asked 6 years ago, i read it

Comment: @Mohamad Alasly and did you check w3c to see if any new features where added since then?

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use this...

```
 <input type="date" min="2020-01-01" max="2020-01-19"/>
```

or if that doesn't works, below is the setup to restrict the date, you can change it dynamically by setting max and min value in javascript.

```js
        $(function () {          

            $("#departure").igDatePicker({
                minValue: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
                maxValue: new Date(2020, 0, 19),
                dateDisplayFormat: "yy/MM/dd dddd"
            });
            
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Ignite UI Required Combined CSS Files -->
    <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2019.2/latest/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2019.2/latest/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        h3 {
            font-size: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .group-fields {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .group-fields label {
            display: block;
            line-height: 18px;
        }

        .group-fields .inline {
            display: inline;
        }

        .group-fields .ui-igcheckbox-normal {
            margin-right: 5px;
            float: left;
        }

        .group-fields .ui-igedit-container {
            width: 230px;
        }

        .clearfix:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

        .group-fields.clearfix > div {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Ignite UI Required Combined JavaScript Files -->
    <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2019.2/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/2019.2/latest/js/infragistics.lob.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
    <div class="group-fields clearfix">
        <div>
            <label for="departure">Please enter date between 1 Jan to 19 Jan 2020</label>
            <input id="departure" />
        </div>
      
    
    </body>
</html>
```