# limit a select dates in date range picker and disable other days javascript Set maximum date dynamically

Tags: javascript, date

Using pure JavaScript build methods without any library or plugin (Dayjs, Moment.Js or date-fns).

Allow to choose **2 months (60 days)** only in date range picker dynamically set for max date.

First I choose start date as today's date or any date on that day.
Then the end date to choose is only within 2 months (60 days).
Other dates must be in disabled state.

HTML min and max attributes not possible to use. In that have to set the hardcoded date for min and max date.
Should be dynamically set for max date in date picker and disable other days.

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="form" class="form">
        <div class="form__control">
            <input type="date" id="input__date" />
                <small class="erorr__Msgs">Select date within 60 days only </small>         
        </div>
        <button class="get__Date" onclick="rangeDate()">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

function rangeDate() {

    let selectedDate = document.querySelector("#input__date").value;
    console.log("selectedDate:" + selectedDate);
    var daystimestamp = new Date().getTime() + (60 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
                                              // day hour min sec msec
    if(daystimestamp < selectedDate) {
    
    } else(daystimestamp>= selectedDate){
          }
}
```

I add the jquery code to the better understand the question:

```
$("").datepicker({
    dateformat:"dd-m-yyy",
    maxDate:'3M',
    minDate:'-3M'
});
```

`maxDate` is set to 3M i.e. 3 months (90 days). It is possible to set days like this in pure javascript without any library or plugin.

And the the max date should be carry forwarded.

Example:

If selected  in Dec 1 2020 then max date selection should not exceed more than 2 months (60 days) dates after 1 feb 2021 should be disabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable certain dates from html5 datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182544/disable-certain-dates-from-html5-datepicker)

Comment: @Omri not possible to use HTML min and max attributes.add some details above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code sample where I defined in the code the `min` and `max` date of the `input[type=date]`. You can change `minDate` to be every day you want, and the `maxDate` will be defined accordingly with `+ 60` days.

```js
let dtElem = document.getElementById('datetime');
let minDate = new Date();
let maxDate = new Date();
maxDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 60);

dtElem.min = formatDate(minDate);
dtElem.max = formatDate(maxDate);

console.log(formatDate(minDate));
console.log(formatDate(maxDate));


function formatDate(date) {
  let dd = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  let mm = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  let yyyy = date.getFullYear();
  return `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="datetime">
```

Comment: thank for solution.There are some changes i will look in it