# Textfield type date in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, uitextfield, textfield

I have a requirement to display start and end-date in material UI. The end-date field must not allow users to select before dates from selected start-date. I am using text field type date material UI, but is not working. please help

```
<TextField 
    type="date"
    defaultValue={moment().format("yyyy-mm-dd")}  
    onChange={endDate}
    InputProps={{
       min: "2020-01-04",
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [limit a select dates in date range picker and disable other days javascript Set maximum date dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64255771/limit-a-select-dates-in-date-range-picker-and-disable-other-days-javascript-set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code snippet. It should do the trick.

```
<TextField
  InputProps={{inputProps: { min: "2020-05-01", max: "2020-05-04"} }}
/>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for you help. I changed your code, since I am getting date from state variable     InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: `${startDate}`, max:""}, }} it worked. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `onChange` prop always accepts a function to invoke when input's content changes. It propagates a html `event`, eg.

```
<TextField 
    type="date"
    defaultValue={moment().format("yyyy-mm-dd")}  
    onChange={(e) => console.log(`your input's value is: ${event.target.value}`) }
    InputProps={{
       min: "2020-01-04",
    }}
/>
```