# enable specific dates in datepicker (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker

I have a simple datepicker

```
<input type="date">
```

How to enable only some given specific dates on this datepicker

```
array = [{"date":"06-April-2021"},{"date":"11-April-2021"},{"date":"17-April-2021"}]
```

There were some solutions with jquery but how to achieve this through javascript

Comment: When you use jQuery datepicker, why don't use jQuery ?

Comment: if you're using an html5 date element your control is limited to min and max date - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182544/disable-certain-dates-from-html5-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

HTML datepicker  supports only min/max attribute. You might want to consider other date picker controls such as [bootstrap](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled)

Comment: This isn't an answer. It's a comment

Comment: I think if the answer of question decided based on length then yes it's comment. However for the question it's answer for sure :). As a practice if it needs to removed from answer and moved as comment, I would gladly do that. At times when users are looking for answer on SO, the miss comments while the correct answer would be hidden in comments