# Disable specific dates in Blazor

Tags: c#, date, datetime, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have some fields in my editform. So here based on my Transport dropdown value selection , shipping date(Datetime) should disable the dates in its calendar.
So here is goes.

```
 <div class="form-group col">
  <label>Main Transport</label>
    @if (lstTransports != null)
      {
         <InputSelect id="txtMainTransport" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@trade.transport" @onchange="OnMainTransportValueChange">
         <option selected value="-1">-Select-</option>
         @foreach (var transport in lstTransports)
           {
              <option value="@transport.id">@transport.id</option>
           }
          </InputSelect>
          <ValidationMessage For="@(() => trade.transport)" />
         }
 </div>

   <div class="form-group col">
         <label>Estimated Shipping Date</label>
            <InputDate id="shippingDate" @bind-Value="@trade.shippingDate" @bind-Value:format="dd/mm/yyyy"  class="form-control" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => trade.shippingDate)" />
       </div>
```

here is the onchange function:

```
private async void OnMainTransportValueChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            trade.transport= e.Value.ToString();
            if(trade.transport == "Sea")
            {
                //here it should have my date disable code
                
            }
        }
```

Now in onchange based on Transport value i want to disable by Shipping date Calendar dates.
So if `Transport == Sea` then the  dates `less than Datetime.Today.AddDays(5)`in shipping date calendar should be disabled.

How can i handle it in  c# ? I tried to modify by shipping date id but it doesn't seem to detect the id value. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me

```
    <InputDate @bind-Value="@myClass.shippingDate" @attributes="@shippingDateAttributes"  />
```

...

```
@code {
    Dictionary<string, object>? shippingDateAttributes = new();

private async void OnMainTransportValueChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            trade.transport= e.Value.ToString();
            if(trade.transport == "Sea")
            {
                //here it should have my date disable code
                string maxDate = (DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(5)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                shippingDateAttributes.Add("max", maxDate);
               StateHasChanged();
            }
        }
   }
```

You need also some logic to make sure you don't add the attribute twice.  So ideally you would remove the 'max' attribute first before you add it.

Here is a reference I used for this post:
[Disable Dates for DateTime picker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56483029/10787774)

Comment: Very well answered. Thanks a lot