# How do i disable future dates in React Js while selecting dates

Tags: html, reactjs, date, datetime, input

I am using this

```
<input type="date" value={defaultValue || "MM/DD/YYYY"} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

How i can disable future dates (for birth-date) ?

NOTE:

I ended up solving this ,

```
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
<input type="date"  onChange={this.handleChange} max={today} />
```

[image: works well]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable certain dates from html5 datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182544/disable-certain-dates-from-html5-datepicker)

Comment: Awesome . it did. Thank you . I ended up using this 

        var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
            <input type="date" i max={today} />