# Disable holiday dates on HTML 5 input type date

Tags: html, date

We are using `<input type="date"/>`.

How can we make holiday dates disabled so that users cannot select the date?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable certain dates from html5 datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182544/disable-certain-dates-from-html5-datepicker)

Comment: The link has explained about disabling the rang of dates. MIN and MAX attribute. I want to disabled specific dates like Christmas , Thankgiving , Easter date

Comment: yes, but the link explains that it is not possible, unless there has been changes since it was posted (9 years ago) but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Yes, you are correct; the post was old, which is why I brought it up once more to see if anyone had the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, I built a function that takes today's date, checks it against an array of holiday dates and increments the date until it doesn't match an array entry. I store the holidays in a separate file so that it can be updated annually without impacted the rest of the codebase.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).