# How can I disable any day in an HTML input where the date is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-input

I have a page in **React** where I use browser input. How can I block any calendar day I specify in the relevant input?

```
<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" value="2018-07-22"/>
```

I need to prevent the user from making selections on special days I specify.

I know that the **calendar** is limited by values ​​such as **min-max**, but what I want is not to disable the days in a date range. I want to disable and prevent a date from being selected directly from any day or year in the calendar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable certain dates from html5 datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182544/disable-certain-dates-from-html5-datepicker)

Comment: I read this example without opening the title. It says it can't be done, but I wanted to try my luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use package like `react-datepicker` and exclude the dates you want to disabled. Because achieving similar functionality with the standard HTML input date field can be challenging, especially without the support of the min and max attributes

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-x9poca?file=src%2FApp.jsx

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const disabledDates = ['2023-12-05', '2023-12-10', '2023-12-15'];
  const today = new Date();

  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(today);

  return (
    <>
      <DatePicker
        selected={selectedDate}
        onChange={(date) => setSelectedDate(date)}
        excludeDates={disabledDates.map((date) => new Date(date))}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: @rahmat My goal is not to disable the date by entering minimum and maximum values.
I need to prevent selection of any day of any year in the calendar without entering a date range. I have an array and the dates in it need to block on days in the calendar.

Comment: @urahara Based on the provided code, it should meet your goal of preventing the selection of specific dates without using minimum and maximum values.

Comment: @rahmat Can you add a sandbox where your example runs? When I try by copying it myself, I see that the solution is not provided.

Comment: @urahara try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-yvvyzp?file=src%2FApp.jsx

Comment: The value is not disabled on the calendar in your example. You are just preventing it from being set to state. The user must disable this date. Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can use a package like react-datepicker and exclude the dates you want to disable. I've already updated the answer and provided the sandbox link for you to check.