# Jquery UI datepicker minDate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 input fields(#from and #to).I want the minDate of #to to be set 1 day ahead of the date in the #from.

I used the following code to set minDate,the same as the date in #from :

```
    $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", document.getElementById("from").value);
```

I have no clue as to how to set it a day ahead.

For Example,if #from has the value '07/09/2013',I want the minDate of #to to be '07/10/2013'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following, instead of value, use 'getDate' and add 1 day to it

```
$("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", $("#from").datepicker('getDate') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#from").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateStr) {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      if (date) {
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
      }
      $("#to").datepicker('setDate', date);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

var dt = document.getElementById("from").value    // you can use jquery here
then increment the date (follow below link)
[Incrementing a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/javascript-date-increment-question)
then bind your datepicker using your +1date