# Bootstrap DatePicker - Setting the date to Tomorrow

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a button which sets the datepicker to tomorrow using the following code:

```js
$("#txtDateOfJourney").datepicker({ startDate: '+1d'});
```

But it's not working.

[**Here's a demo in fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/86k80L59/)

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only pass in the options (as in `datepicker({ startDate: '+1d'})`) when you're initializing the controller.  Since it's already initialized you don't need to do that.  Instead you want to use the [`setDate()`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#setdate) method and then pass in <del>[the javascript date representation of tomorrow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3674539/1366033)</del> a string representing the relative date like this:

```js
$('#txtDateOfJourney').datepicker('setDate', "+1d");
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
$('#btnTomorrow').click(function() {     
  $('#txtDateOfJourney').datepicker('setDate', "+1d");
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txtDateOfJourney" class="datepicker" />
<button type="button" id="btnTomorrow" class="btn btn-info">Tomorrow</button>
```

Comment: Thanks KyleMit! Although this works like a charm, I would still want to go with the native way. :-) Any possiblities?

Comment: What do you mean the native way?  This is a native method on the bootstrap-datepicker object and plain old javascript.

Comment: When I say native, I mean native to bootstrap's ability, In a nutshell, I want to make " startDate: '+1d' " to work. Hope you understand.

Comment: @DavidR, I updated the answer to parse the string `+1d` as part of the setDate method.  Although none of this is provided by bootstrap - they're both handled by the bootstrap-datepicker library.  Either way, the exact syntax you're looking for isn't possible, but this will do the same thing.