# Counting weekday cycles in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

My school runs on a 7 day cycle, so if today (2016/02/26) was day 1, tomorrow would be day 0, Monday would be day 2, and the next day 1 would be 2016/03/08. I know it's very strange, but I'm trying to find a way to use the `Date` object in JavaScript and add on one cycle, that is 7 days, not including weekends.

I would like to emphasize that weekends DO NOT COUNT towards day counting. I'm trying to find a way to omit weekends and easily find the next day 1 or day 5 or whatever.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/incrementing-a-date-in-javascript/3674550#3674550

Comment: *"if today (2016/02/26) was day 1, tomorrow would be day 2"* -  But that puts day 2 on a weekend.

Comment: To add 7 day is just `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are either 1 or 2 weekends in your 7-day school cycle, depending on the start day of the cycle, so the actual cycle length is either 9 or 11 days.  The Date.getDay() method gives you access to the day of the week, so a possible solutions might look like this:

```
var myDate= new Date();
switch(true) {
//Sunday=0, Saturday=6
case(myDate.getDay() % 6 == 0) :  alert('weekend!'); return;
case (myDate.getDay() < 4) :  // Mon, Tues, Wed
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 9);
    break;
case (myDate.getDay() < 6) :  // Thu, Fri
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 11);
    break;
}
```

Comment: My mistake... no weekends. So it's adding 7 days without including weekends.

Comment: Then newDate= myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+7);

Comment: That adds 7 days, but still counts weekends in those 7 days.