# Easiest way to find a date, X duration from another date, in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to have the following functionality in moment js, for my app.

```
var nDay = moment(2007, 0, 28).next('date'); //--> 2007-0-29T00:00:00.00
var pDay = moment(2007, 0, 28).previous('date'); //--> 2007-0-27T00:00:00.00
```

Similarly:

```
.next('week'), .next('month')
```

and  gets the particular date back.

I know momentjs has manipulation methods, but using them is a pain as it mutates the original. Even with the `.clone()`, it's not easy.

So guys, how to implement this `next()`, and `previous()` methods, in moment or in js?

Or, what is the easiest way to find the day after a particular day?

Comment: Checkout the moment docs - read through them and see if you can find what you need. They have covered almost everything. Start out at the [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/add/) section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incrementing a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/incrementing-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: duration, used with add(), and subtract(),  is not giving me the result i want. Also it mutates  the original. So, it can be done with some formating and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

As you said in the question, you can use moment manipulation functions like [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) and [`subtract`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) along with [`clone`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/) to avoid original object mutation.

To add a custom function to moment use [`moment.fn`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/).

Moment manipulation functions accept `'months'`, `'weeks'`, `'days'` etc as parameter, while it seems that you want to use `'month'`, `'week'`, `'date'`, so you need to convert your input strings to moment equivalent.

Here there is a working example:

```js
moment.fn.next = function(unit){
  // Convert input to strings used by moment
  unit = unit === 'date' ? 'days' : unit;
  if( unit === 'month' || unit === 'week'){
    unit += 's';
  }
  
  return this.clone().add(1, unit);
}

moment.fn.previous = function(unit){
  // Convert input to strings used by moment
  unit = unit === 'date' ? 'days' : unit;
  if( unit === 'month' || unit === 'week'){
    unit += 's';
  }
  
  return this.clone().subtract(1, unit);
}

var nDay = moment([2007, 0, 28]).next('date');
var pDay = moment([2007, 0, 28]).previous('date');
var nMonth = moment([2007, 0, 28]).next('month');
console.log(nDay.format());
console.log(pDay.format());
console.log(nMonth.format());
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```