# Incrementing an ISO date string in JavaScript (e.g. '2014-03-30' -> '2014-03-31')

Tags: javascript

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/incrementing-a-date-in-javascript), but I need to process ISO strings.

I've tried to adapt the solution from the other question:

```
var getNextDay = function(day) {
    var date = new Date(day);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    return date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
};
```

This actually works in most cases, e.g. getNextDay('2014-03-31') returns '2014-04-01'.

However, getNextDay('2014-03-30') gives me '2014-03-30' (The full string before slicing is '2014-03-30T23:00:00.000Z')

Does anyone know why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: Try `setUTCDdate` and `getUTCDate` instead. It seems to be a daylight-saving-timing issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by Daylight saving adjustment that happened on that date. [March 30, 2014: Europe starts Daylight Saving Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/europe-starts-dst-2014.html)

Fix it by using UTCDate instead:

```
var getNextDay = function(day) {
    var date = new Date(day);
    date.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() + 1);
    return date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
};
```