# how change date weekly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to use this code ([Change week in a calendar when a button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316754/change-week-in-a-calendar-when-a-button-is-clicked)) to display the date of a whole week from Sunday to Saturday. But the problem is that for example November 2020 ends on the 30th, but the script continues to count 31, 32, 33, 34, 35 ..

```js
 function renderCalender(d){
          let t = d.getDay();
             let weekday = document.querySelectorAll(".weekday");
             for (let i = 0, j = 1; i < weekday.length; i++) {
                 let x = t-i;
                 if (t > i) {
                     weekday[i].innerHTML = `${d.getMonth()+1}/${d.getDate()-x}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
                 } else if (t < i) {
                     weekday[i].innerHTML = `${d.getMonth()+1}/${d.getDate()+j}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
                     j++
                 } else if (t === i) {
                     weekday[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(100, 100, 100)";
                     weekday[i].innerHTML = `${d.getMonth()+1}/${d.getDate()}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
                 }
             }
             }



             function changeForm (form) {
                 let otherForms = document.querySelectorAll(".inquiry-selection-active");
                 for (let i = 0; i < otherForms.length; i++) {
                     otherForms[i].className = "inquiry-selection";
                 }

                 let commissionForm = document.getElementById(`${form.value}`);
                 commissionForm.className = 'inquiry-selection-active';
             }

             function nextWeek(){
             var currentDate = new Date()
             currentDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime()+7*24*60*60*1000); //append date with 7 days and pass to render function
             renderCalender(currentDate);
             }
             renderCalender(new Date());
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
         <div id="est-finish-dates">
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <th>Sunday<br/>(<span class="weekday"></span>)</th>
                  <th>Monday<br/>(<span class="weekday"></span>)</th>
                  <th>Tuesday<br/>(<span class="weekday"></span>)</th>
                  <th>Wednesday<br/>(<span class="weekday"></span>)</th>
                  <th>Thursday<br/>(<span class="weekday"></span>)</th>
                  <th>Friday<br/>(<span class="weekday"></span>)</th>
                  <th>Saturday<br/>(<span class="weekday"></span>)</th>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
```

any ideas you give me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like:

```js
function lastSunday(dateArg = false){
  const d = dateArg ? new Date(dateArg) : new Date;
  let q = d.getTime(), n = 86400000;
  while(d.getDay() !== 0){
    q -= n; d.setTime(q);
  }
  d.setHours(0); d.setMinutes(0); d.setSeconds(0); d.setMilliseconds(0);
  return d;
}
console.log(lastSunday().toString());
console.log(lastSunday('October 3, 2020').toString());
console.log(lastSunday('December 9, 2020').toString());
```

Note that `n` is 24 hours is milliseconds.