# How to restructure JSON object array and add 1 day to object date?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i make json object from

```
{
    "Public_Holiday": [{
          "id": 1,
          "date": "2018-12-31T15:59:14.000Z"
    }]
}
```

Into this and add momentjs

```
{
    "Public_Holiday": [{
          "id": 1,
          "date": "2019-1-1"
    }]
}
```

And i tried to restructure json by doing

```
const items = await jsonfile.readFile('./json/data.json');
const objKey = Object.keys(items);
const json_struct = objKey.map((key) => {
    tablename: key,
    table: items[key]
})
```

So how can i filtered the json_struct with every object date and increment it by 1?

Comment: Depend on your preference,  you can use moment js library for format the date, or it could be regular expression to split the  things out if that just a string.

Comment: What is the algorithm to convert "2018-12-31T15:59:14.000Z" to "2019-1-1"?

Comment: actually im using convert-excel-to-json library that use another library called sheetjs to parse excel document into json. the output will appear like code above but the library itself have a problem in parsing date from excel. Then im using another alerternative by using momenjs to add 1 day from the ISO based timestamp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incrementing a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/incrementing-a-date-in-javascript)