# Error incrementing days to a specific date

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to increment one *day* to a given *date*. My code, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/incrementing-a-date-in-javascript/3674550), looks like:

```
var date = getDateFromUIControl();
var backupDate = new Date();
backupDate.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
```

However, I'm seeing a strange behaviour. Today is December 5th, 2019. If the user selects January 1, 2020 (stored in  `date` variable), then `backupDate` ends up being January 2nd, 2019, instead of 2020. What is wrong with this code? How should I go about incrementing the date, if what I'm doing is wrong?

Note: because of whatever policies my company has, I can't use any JavaScript library other than jQuery.

Comment: what is the value of date?

Comment: @PranavRamachandran the value of date is 2020/01/01, so I'm expecting backupDate to be 2020/01/02, and instead I'm getting 2019/01/02.

Comment: Updated my solution, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date()` returns the current Date(example: 05/12/2019). You are just changing the date alone in current date. Still the year is 2019.

it should be like,

```
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
```

if you can't change the original date object, then it can be done like this,

```
var changedDate = new Date(date);
changedDate.setDate(changedDate.getDate() + 1);
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot change `date`, I need to create another object and add the date there. How should I go about it? Thanks!

Comment: @FernandoGómez updated the solution based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = getDateFromUIControl();
var backupDate = new Date();
backupDate.setDate(new Date(date).getDate() + 1);
```

Comment: the date variable holds a date like 2019/01/02 as per the problem. backupDate is just holding a date object. we will add 1 day to date object of 'date' variable like new Date(date).getDate() + 1 and pass it to setDate Method of Date prototype.

Answer (score 0):

`nextDay` is one day after `date`:

```
var date = getDateFromUIControl();
var nextDay = new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()+1);
```

Also you don't need to worry about overflowing `d.getDate()+1` (e.g. 31+1) - the Date constructor is smart enough to go into the next month.