# I have a date created when a form is submitted. I want to be able to create another date 60 days later

Tags: javascript

I have been able to write my code based on answers to other questions on here however, I am stuck. I am new to coding and teaching myself as I go. I have a spreadsheet that is filled when a form is submitted. There is a date that populates into column B (date of incident). I want to add 60 days to that date for a due date. I have been able to add the 60 days but for only one cell.

I have added a menu in the Ui that has a button to run the function and it works but for that cell. I want to be able to be on the cell that I want the due date added to and when I select it in the Ui have it fill in the date. I am guessing it has something to do with .getActiveCell but I am stuck.

```
function setDuedate()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('2020');
  var dateOfincident = new Date(sheet.getRange('B3').getValue()).getTime();
  var dayInMs = 24*60*60*1000

  var due = dateOfincident + (60*dayInMs)

  sheet.getRange('L3').setValue(new Date(due));
```

Comment: You're asking a JavaScript question, but you've tagged it Java. Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: This doesn't look like Java. `function` is not a valid Java keyword. Is your program perhaps in Javascript? If it is Java, don't use Date. It's use is deprecated.

Comment: If you are using Javascript, you might want to look at moment.js. It has useful functions like `moment("2020-06-20", "YYYY-MM-DD").add(60, 'days');`

Comment: IMO you'll find a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/incrementing-a-date-in-javascript/3674550

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incrementing a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/incrementing-a-date-in-javascript)