# how to show the date after a predefined date with jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a string which contains a date like this: `2021-05-20`
Now I am looking for the next day after this date so i am looking for `2021-05-21`

How can I do that?

```
var date = '2021-05-20';
var dayafter = ??? // should be 2021-05-21

// below gives me the date after today
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
console.log(date);

// but i need the day after a predefined date
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incrementing a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/incrementing-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: No i tried this but this shows the day after the current day. And i need the day after a predefined date

Comment: Here , `new Date()` pass that date i.e : `new Date('2021-05-20')` then try again.

Comment: @Swati Exactly what is was looking for. Thnx a lot