# How to fill missing dates inside array of object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, date, object

I want to fill this object from today's date to next 7 days. Here is my object

```
let obj = {
  "sessions": [{
       "id": 0,
       "available_capacity": 3,
       "date": "15-05-2021"
   },
   {
       "id": 1,
       "available_capacity": 5,
       "date": "16-05-2021"
   },
   {
       "id": 2,
       "available_capacity": 2,
       "date": "18-05-2021"
   }]
}
```

Expected output:

```
let output = {
  "sessions": [{
       "date": "14-05-2021"
   },
   {
       "id": 0,
       "available_capacity": 3,
       "date": "15-05-2021"
   },
   {
       "id": 1,
       "available_capacity": 5,
       "date": "16-05-2021"
   },
   {
       "date": "17-05-2021"
   },
   {
       "id": 2,
       "available_capacity": 2,
       "date": "18-05-2021"
   },
   {
       "date": "19-05-2021"
   },
   {
       "date": "20-05-2021"
   }]
}
```

Here is the code to generate array of dates from today to next 7 days

```js
function getWeekDates() {
    let dates = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
      dates.push(new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 3600 * (i * 24)).toLocaleDateString('en-GB').replace('/', '-').replace('/', '-'));
    }
    console.log(dates);
}

getWeekDates();

//result: ["14-05-2021", "15-05-2021", "16-05-2021", "17-05-2021", "18-05-2021", "19-05-2021", "20-05-2021"]
```

How can I fill in the missing dates?

Comment: Incrementing a Date by a day should be done by adding 1 day, not 24 hours as days are not all 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed, see [*Incrementing a date in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/incrementing-a-date-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to generate the dates array. You can pass the startDate and numberOfDays you need. In your case you can just `dateRange(new Date(), 7)`

```js
const DAY_IN_MS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
const dateRange = (startDate, numOfDays) => {
    const startDateInMs = startDate.getTime()
    return [...Array(numOfDays).keys()].map(i => new Date(startDateInMs + i * DAY_IN_MS).toISOString().slice(0,10))
}

let dates = dateRange(new Date(),7);
console.log(dates);
```

You can use `Array.prototype.map` and return the check if date exists in obj.sessions using `Array.prototype.find` then return the object otherwise just return the same date.
**`Array.prototype.find`** returns undefined if item doesn't exist.

```js
let obj = {
  "sessions": [{
       "id": 0,
       "available_capacity": 3,
       "date": "15-05-2021"
   },
   {
       "id": 1,
       "available_capacity": 5,
       "date": "16-05-2021"
   },
   {
       "id": 2,
       "available_capacity": 2,
       "date": "18-05-2021"
   }]
}
function getWeekDates() {
    let dates = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
      dates.push(new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 3600 * (i * 24)).toLocaleDateString('en-GB').replace('/', '-').replace('/', '-'));
    }
    return dates;
}

let dates = getWeekDates();
let r = dates.map(d => {
  let o = obj.sessions.find(x => x.date === d);
  return o ?? {date: d}
 });
console.log(r);
```

Comment: Incrementing a Date by a day should be done by adding 1 day, not 24 hours as days are not all 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed, see [*Incrementing a date in JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/incrementing-a-date-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like below.

```js
function getWeekDates() {
    let dates = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
      dates.push(new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 3600 * (i * 24)).toLocaleDateString('en-GB').replace('/', '-').replace('/', '-'));
    }
    return dates
}
getWeekDates().map(date => {
    return obj.sessions.find(s => s.date === date) || date
})


/* 

Output

[
    {
        "date": "14-05-2021"
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "available_capacity": 3,
        "date": "15-05-2021"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "available_capacity": 5,
        "date": "16-05-2021"
    },
    {
        "date": "17-05-2021"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "available_capacity": 2,
        "date": "18-05-2021"
    },
    {
        "date": "19-05-2021"
    },
    {
        "date": "20-05-2021"
    }
]
*/
```

Comment: already_present variable is not required. you can directly check the date in the same object. please check my answer.