# How to get day after tomorrow date in dd + / + mm + /yyyy in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Please help me.....

On the web there is only tommorows date not day afters.
I am not able to get the date.

Comment: This is a duplicate question, Please check here the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/incrementing-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: "On the web there is only tommorows date" what does this even mean? the web knows all the dates of the future) . You add two days to the current date ... `date = new Date; date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like  @Bravo already mentioned:

```js
const d=new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()+2);
console.log(d.toLocaleString("en-uk").slice(0,10))
```

Comment: Thanks @Cartsen. But can you please tell how to arrange it in dd + / + mm + / + yyyy format? If you could tell this, it would be very grateful....

Comment: Just changed my post. Look it up there ;-).