# Javascript: date.setDate is broken for a very specific date

Tags: javascript, date

I was looping dates in a while loop and noticed that one of my dates did not increment properly (making the loop go over the same date twice)

More specifically: "2024-03-10"

I then tried to replicate this issue in the dev tools console (in chrome) using this function:

```js
(() => {
  let d = new Date("2024-03-10")
  console.log("current day", d.toISOString())
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)
  console.log("next day", d.toISOString())
})()
```

And the output I receive is:

```
current day 2024-03-10T00:00:00.000Z
next day 2024-03-10T23:00:00.000Z
```

As you can see, it only added 23h to the date so we are still in 2024-03-10.
Is anyone else able to reproduce this error? I get this problem in both NodeJS and Chrome Console...

**EDIT**
As Daniel A. White and Christian Fritz pointed out, it's because of daylight saving time.

So what's the solution? How do I add 1 more day to a date regardless of the time shift?

Comment: are you hitting a daylight saving time? what timezone are you in?

Comment: yes he is https://www.google.com/search?q=2024+dst+dates

Comment: How do I make javascript ignore that? I want to increment the date by 1 day

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5757691/1491895) in the linked question shows how to deal with the DST change.

Comment: @TheLoneCoder - Keep in mind that internally, a `Date` object is just a numeric timestamp - not an actual "date".  You created a timestamp on a date at midnight UTC, but then incremented it by 24 hours in local time.  Since there's only 23 hours on that particular local day in your time zone (due to start of DST), that's why you get the result that you do.  A simple solution, if you're attempting to ignore the time part and just use the date part, is to use `getUTCDate`/`setUTCDate` (which work with UTC) instead of `getDate`/`setDate` (which work with local time).